# Vue + Firebase route to prevent user back to login page after login

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs3, vue-router

I develop SPA using VueJS 3 and firebase. I want prevent user from accessing login page after they login. But it seems the routes are keep looped or error after trying different code.

the routes:

```
{
  path: '/', name: 'login', component: () => import('../views/LoginView.vue')
},
{
  path: '/dashboard', name: 'dashboard', component: () => import('../views/DashboardView.vue'),
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
  },
},
```

the logic(didnt show anything):

```
const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const removeListener = onAuthStateChanged(
      getAuth(),
      (user) => {
        removeListener()
        resolve(user)
      },
      reject
    )
  })
}

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) =>{
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (await getCurrentUser()) {
      next()
    } else {
      next("/")
    }
  } else {
    next("/dashboard")
  } 
})
```

this one keep looping:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) =>{
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (await getCurrentUser()) {
      next()
    } else {
      next("/")
    }
  } 
  next("/dashboard")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the [Vue Router Doc](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) :

> You must call "next" exactly once in any given pass through a navigation guard. It can appear more than once, but only if the logical paths have no overlap, otherwise the hook will never be resolved or produce errors.:

They provide those examples :

```js
// BAD
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Login' && !isAuthenticated) next({ name: 'Login' })
  // if the user is not authenticated, `next` is called twice
  next()
})

// GOOD
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Login' && !isAuthenticated) next({ name: 'Login' })
  else next()
})
```

Also, make sure you do not have a infinite loop :

`next("/dashboad")` forces a redirection to the Dashboard page, no matter what page we come from. You may end in a loop where every page redirects to Dashboard, **including** the Dashboard page itself